# Travelling to the US 3 times in 12 months

Tags: visas, usa

I traveled to the US in October 2017 and I am returning in February 2018. Even though I am going to the same place to see the same person, do I need to inform authorities of the new dates of travel? I don't want to be turned away for such a trivial matter.

Comment: Are you talking about information you gave in an ESTA application (even though the question is tagged "visas"). This does not need to be updated unless something related to your _eligibility_ changes.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you have a valid visa or ESTA authorization, it is not necessary to do anything before checking in for your flight or arriving at the border, when you will give your US address for that trip.

This is true whether you're traveling with a visa, with ESTA authorization, with some other visa-free status, or as a US citizen or permanent resident.